# Rails & EC2 API - how can I monitor an EC2 instance status and trigger a method on 'running'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm wondering if there is a method by which I can monitor the status of an instance on EC2, and perform some action when it changes. Currently I'm using long polling, but this is generating a lot of EC2 API requests; is there is a better way?

Comment: did you see it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/Instance.html#monitoring-instance_method

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use waiters, as detailed in EC2 API, which poll AWS in the background.

Makes most sense when done as part of a background process.